# Nodejs code giving output as array of promise instead of resolved value?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a Nodejs expressJs feature where I am using Mysql and Sequelize.
My issue is that in the code instead of getting resolved value I am getting array of promise
and I do not know why.

I am pasting the code here:

```
exports.startQuiz = async (req) => {
    let quizId = req.params.quizId;
    let questns = await questionsModal.findAll({
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt', "updatedAt", "choice", "eid"] }
    },{
        where:{
            eid: quizId
        }
    });
    let opsArr = [];
    let qid, option, optnValue;
    var c = await questns.map( async q => {
        // console.log("q data", q);
        optnValue = await optionsModal.findOne({ where: {qid: q.toJSON().id}});
        optnValue = optnValue.toJSON();
        qid = q.toJSON().id;
        
        // console.log("option --> ", qid, optnValue.option); //showing right value
        return {qid, option: optnValue.option};
    });
    console.log("c :", c); // showing array of Promises.
    return {questns};
}
```

I want the value c to be printed as an array of values but I am getting array of promises.
While I consoleing the "option" that is commented out code then its showing me the right values.

Why its happening ?

Comment: The answer for this kind of scenarios are here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305545/nodejs-code-giving-output-as-array-of-promise-instead-of-resolved-value

Comment: Thank you for this. This is what i needed.